# Foreach inside Foreach - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get the following

```
   <li class="player">
        <a class="playerinfo>
            <span class="playernumber">1</span>
            <span class="playername">Angel</span>
        </a>
    </li> 
   <li class="player">
        <a class="playerinfo>
            <span class="playernumber">2</span>
            <span class="playername">Shamak</span>
        </a>
    </li>
   <li class="player">
        <a class="playerinfo>
            <span class="playernumber">4</span>
            <span class="playername">Koal</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I need to get the players number and players name from 2 different foreach but I can't find a solution is it really possible to Foreach inside Foreach

Here is what I've tried so far

```
 $repeatable1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-box-text', true);


       foreach($repeatable1['playersnum'] as $num) {

              echo '<li class="player">';

              echo '<a class="playerinfo">';

              echo ' <span class="playernumber">'.$num.'</span>';


       } 

         foreach($repeatable1['playersname'] as $name) {

                echo '<span class="playername">'.$name.'</span>';

                echo '</a></li>';

       }
```

Thanks

Comment: your code is 2 separate foreach() loops, not one embedded in another.

Comment: thanks for the reply I did that also but I'm not getting the output that I want, that's why I'm asking if there is a way to really put 2 foreach()loops in one

Comment: whats the array structure of `$repeatable1` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current loops are not nested. However, you can use the `index` to print all the data you need at once. The index will take the values 0,1,2,3...

```
<?php foreach($repeatable1['playersname'] as $index=> $value):?>
    <li class="player">
        <a class="playerinfo>
            <span class="playernumber"><?php echo $repeatable1['playersnum'][$index]; ?></span>
            <span class="playername"><?php echo $value; ?></span>
        </a>
    </li> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**However**: Ideally, you will restructure the `$repeatable` array to have a `'player'` property that will have an entry for sum and for name.

```
$repeatable = [
    "player" => [
        ["name"=>"The Name","sum"=>100],
        ["name"=>"The other name","sum"=>200],
        ...
    ]
];
```